# Importing JSON to Realm.io

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary, realm

I've just started out using Realm, mainly to be able to pre-populate my app with data. So I figured the easiest way to do this would be by importing an existing JSON-file to my app, but I've run into a few problems.

The file I'm trying to import is formatted like this:

> { "DDD" : "3D Systems Corporation", "MMM" : "3M Company", "WBAI" :
>   "500.com Limited", "WUBA" : "58.com Inc.", "AHC" : "A.H. Belo
>   Corporation", "ATEN" : "A10 Networks, Inc.", "AAC" : "AAC Holdings,
>   Inc.", "AIR" : "AAR Corp." }

and I would like to get it into a `Dictionary<String,String>` or a `NSMutuableDictionary`.

My code looks like this:

```
class Stock: RLMObject {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var ticker = ""
}

class Table: RLMObject {
    dynamic var stocks = RLMArray(objectClassName: Stock.className())
}

import Realm

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


        let jsonFilePath:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("nyseDict", ofType: "json")!
        let jsonData:NSData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfMappedFile(jsonFilePath as String) as! NSData
        let error:NSError?
        let json = JSON(jsonData)

        let realm: RLMRealm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

        var table = Table()

        for var i = 0; i < json.count; ++i {

            let myStock = Stock()

            myStock.name = json[i][0].string!
            myStock.ticker = json[i][1].string!

            realm.beginWriteTransaction()
            realm.addObject(myStock)
            table.stocks.addObject(myStock)
            realm.commitWriteTransaction()

        }

        realm.transactionWithBlock() {
            realm.addObject(table)
        }

        for obj in Table.allObjects(){
        println(obj.description)
        }

        return true
    }
```

For starters, I'm getting an error in line number 15: `let collectionDicts:NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: 0, error: &error)` saying that:

> Cannot invoke 'JSONObjectWithData' with an argument list of type
>   '(NSData, options: Int, error: inout NSError?)'

and I'm not quite sure what other way I would initialize it.

Other than that I'm just interested in knowing if there are any other errors you could point out, since I haven't been able to test my code.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: By changing my code to the one above I'm now able to load my app without errors, but still nothing happens when I'm trying to print the object descriptions at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make NSError mutable.

```
var error: NSError?
```

Comment: Just changed my code by using the SwiftyJSON library so that error is now taken care of, I can now load the app without problems, but when I try to print them at the end nothing happens.

Comment: we have no way of knowing what is happening inside `Stockdata.createInDefaultRealmWithObject(stocker)` - for all we know it could be returning empty data.  You really should learn how to sit down and debug your code before you ask people on SO.

Comment: That's a standard function, not one I created.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is a dictionary, but you're accessing it as an array of arrays (`myStock.name = json[i][0].string!`). Here's some sample code I just wrote to verify that if you change the way you access your JSON data, everything should work:

```
let json = [
    "DDD": "3D Systems Corporation",
    "MMM": "3M Company",
    "WBAI": "500.com Limited",
    "WUBA": "58.com Inc.",
    "AHC": "A.H. Belo Corporation",
    "ATEN": "A10 Networks, Inc.",
    "AAC": "AAC Holdings, Inc.",
    "AIR": "AAR Corp."
]

let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()

let table = Table()

for (key, value) in json {

    let myStock = Stock()

    myStock.name = key
    myStock.ticker = value

    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    realm.addObject(myStock)
    table.stocks.addObject(myStock)
    realm.commitWriteTransaction()
}

realm.transactionWithBlock() {
    realm.addObject(table)
}

for obj in Table.allObjects() {
    println(obj.description)
}
```

As a side note, you'll see improved performance if you batch your write transactions like so:

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.beginWriteTransaction()

let table = Table()
realm.addObject(table)

for (key, value) in json {
    let myStock = Stock()
    myStock.name = key
    myStock.ticker = value
    table.stocks.addObject(myStock)
}

realm.commitWriteTransaction()

for obj in Table.allObjects() {
    println(obj.description)
}
```

Comment: is there a benefit/optimization when using public func add<S>(_ objects: S, update: Bool = default) where S : Sequence, S.Element : RealmSwift.Object vs. looping through and adding an object?

Comment: For an arbitrary `Sequence, it'll add each element one by one, but if the `Sequence` is a `RealmCollection`, there are often optimizations.